# Shopware 6 App deployment storefront re-building neccessary?

Tags: shopware6

I am developing a shopware 6 app using the storefront. I am building the storefront at my dev environment (./bin/build-storefront.sh), which creates a bundle.js in the dist directory. I do also have a demo store, where I upload the zip file including the dist bundle. But the app's javascript won't be executed, only after building the storefront there as well. There is no way to encourage the future customers to re-built their storefront after installing my app. What am I missing here.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely shouldn't have to re-compile the assets when you ship your app with the pre-compiled assets. That wouldn't be possible in many cases anyway, since nodejs is not a requirement for production environments.

Keep in mind though, that `build-storefront.sh` does three things:

1. Compile the sources (that'll be the assets in the `dist` directory)
2. Move the assets from the plugin directories to Shopware's `public` dir (`bin/console assets:install`)
3. Compile the themes (`bin/console theme:compile`). This will compile the `scss` assets and concatenate all the pre-compiled JavaScript into the single asset `all.js`.

The first step should be done on the developers side. The other two steps however will have to be executed on every change. For apps this should happen on the app lifecycle events, e.g. when you install, update and activate an app. Only uploading the archive of your app over and over again will replace the files in app's directory, however you will still have to re-install the app for the changed assets to be collected. Either that, or you increase the version and update the app.

There recently was a bug which deleted assets after the build process within plugin directories. [This got fixed with the release of 6.5.1.1](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/v6.5.1.1/changelog/release-6-5-1-1/2023-05-30-fix-webpack-cleanup-config.md). If you're on an earlier version, check that your compiled assets haven't been deleted before archiving due to this bug and are included.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I must clarify, that I increase the version and use the update function. Anyways the whole javascript bundle is ignored. Changes in the config.xml and twig files are recognized by the update.

Comment: There recently was a bug which deleted assets after the build process. [This got fixed with the release of 6.5.1.1](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/v6.5.1.1/changelog/release-6-5-1-1/2023-05-30-fix-webpack-cleanup-config.md). If you're on an earlier version, check that your compiled assets haven't been deleted before archiving due to this bug and are included.

Comment: I still could not figure out what to do here exactly. What actions do I have to make in my lifecycle events? I still got the problem, that the code is not executed before I rebuild the storefront.

Comment: I also installed the latest version of dockware to build the storefront. There is a generated js file inside the dist folder (dist/storefront/js/myapp.js). Still not working.

Comment: @dneustadt I know this is already old, but I do have the same question. [Here](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-javascript.html) it says that after adding some custom javascript within an app to be injected into the storefront, one has to rebuild storefront. Is there any way to bind building the storefront to the app installation? There  is no info about that. That's what the initial question is about. If my clients are using Shopware SaaS (cloud shop) they would not be able to trigger storefront building from the server side.